# Looking to post a few values on a web page

Tags: web, arduino, particle-photon

I have set up particle photon board to read input values from 4 sensors and I like to learn how to post it in a web page. But my skills are bare. I like to know how to proceed.

Comment: What did you do until now with your code?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it with Ethernet shield or Arduino Ethernet. I've found this tutorial which may help you: 
http://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/

When you setup everything, type between `<body>` and `</body>` your data. Then you can access it after plugging arduino to your network and typing its ip in your browser.